# what does the original httpd-vhosts.conf look like?

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP Version 7.3.4 which comes with Apache 2.4.  I just went through the biggest learning lesson...make a backup of the original httpd-vhosts.conf file in case I need to reference it again.   Unfortunately I didn't and need to get back to how it looks because I did some dramatic modifications on that file.

The thing that is driving me crazy is that the [Apache 2.4 documentation site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html), does not have a full representation of what their httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like.

Does anyone know where I can see a copy of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `httpd-vhosts.conf` file is usually empty by default in many installations of Apache, same goes for Xampp, it usually only contains a few commented examples of `<VirtualHost>` and nothing else, so you do not need to worry about backing it up or anything, unless you have configured your own custom rules in it.